# Storing UniqueIdentifier as a reference to other states

Tags: corda

I have a `PurchaseOrder state` where the primary key would be `PurchaseOrderID` and `SupplierName`.

I have another `LetterOfCredit state` which need to refer the above state so that we can get `PurchaseOrder` from vault if we have `LetterOfCredit state`.

- So one way is I store `PurchaseOrderID` and `SupplierName` in
  `LetterOfCredit` also
- or I can store the `UniqueIdentifier` of the
  `PurchaseOrder state` in `LetterOfCredit state`.
- or I generate a unique
  `transactionID` myself and store in both the states as a separate field.

Which should be the correct way?

Question 2: If I go with second approach, than is it correct to generate `UniqueIdentifier` from [`external id`, `id`] to query for the state from vault.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `purchaseOrder` state is a linear state then it's uniquely identified with it's `linearId` which happens to be a `UniqueIdentifier`. Now you can randomly generate the identifier from `UniqueIdentifier()` or you can pass the externalId (which you would like to use to be in sync with your upstream systems) to it and to get back the uniqueIdentifier use `UniqueIdentifier.fromString(externalId)` . 
Go with the 2nd approach and get the UniqueIdentifier from externalId as stated above.

Comment: Thanks, I missed this method `UniqueIdentifier.fromString(externalId)`